# How to dynamically set value for Angularjs select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-select

In Angularjs, I try to set option dynamically from program. But, I am not able to set.

Please support.

Verify comment's reference link for more details.

Thanks in Advance!

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        "AngularJS select example"
        <br />
         <br />
        <select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-change="plotRulegraph()">
           <option ng-selected="{{ option.key == mail_notification }}"
                   ng-repeat="option in mail_notifications"
                   value="{{option.key}}">
             {{option.value}}
           </option>
        </select>
        <br />                
    </div>
</div>
```

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.mail_notifications = [
        {
            "key": 0,
            "value": "For any event on all my projects"
        },
        {
            "key":1,
            "value": "For any event on the selected projects only..."
        },
        {
            "key": 2,
            "value": "Only for things I watch or I'm involved in"
        },
        {
            "key": 3,
            "value": "Only for things I am assigned to"
        }
    ];
    $scope.mail_notification = 3;

     $scope.plotRulegraph = function() {
            $scope.mail_notification=2;
     }
});
```

Comment: For reference:. https://jsfiddle.net/cxft72ur/

Comment: In this sample, I am setting default value. But, it's not behaving as per my expectation

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, try reading the readily available documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `ng-selected` with `ng-model`.

When the values are a type other that strings, use the `ng-value` directive:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        "AngularJS select example"
        <br />
         <br />
        <select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-change="plotRulegraph()">
           <option ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶e̶l̶e̶c̶t̶e̶d̶=̶"̶{̶{̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶k̶e̶y̶ ̶=̶=̶ ̶m̶a̶i̶l̶_̶n̶o̶t̶i̶f̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶}̶}̶"
                   ng-repeat="option in mail_notifications"
                   ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶{̶{̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶k̶e̶y̶}̶}̶"̶
                   ng-value="option.key">
             {{option.value}}
           </option>
        </select>
        <br />                
    </div>
</div>
```

With interpolation with double curley braces `{{ }}`, the values are converted to strings. The `<select>` directive uses strict equality when comparing values. Numeric keys are not equal to string keys. The `ng-value` directive retains the proper type.

From the Docs:

> > Note: `ngSelected` does not interact with the `<select>` and `ngModel` directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using `ngModel` on the `<select>`, you should not use `ngSelected` on the options, as `ngModel` will set the `<select>` value and selected options.
>
> — [AngularJS `ng-selected` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected#overview)

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-value Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue)
- [AngularJS `<select>` API - Using `ngValue` to bind the model to an array of objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngvalue-to-bind-the-model-to-an-array-of-objects)

---

## Update

The example requires AngularJS V1.5 or greater.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/dYyH5tagpwUFFYp9M1Jr?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. But, please correct me, what i have done wrong in this link. https://jsfiddle.net/8vrL9bwd/ .almost, I followed your instruction.I am setting model value. bur, it's not selecting.

Comment: Your Fiddle uses an obsolete version of AngularJS. See update to answer.